# Parameter string to class type + id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oop

Simplified reporting example here:

Say I have three different value objects all with an ID property:

```
public class ObjectA() { int ID { get; set; } }
public class ObjectB() { int ID { get; set; } }
public class ObjectC() { int ID { get; set; } }
```

And say I want to use a "ClassTypePlusID" parameter from a URL like so:

```
http://www.example.com/show/A1
http://www.example.com/show/B3
http://www.example.com/show/C2
```

Now, in my view model its pretty easy to extract the type (the A, B, or C) and the ID (the 1, 3, or 2).  And from there, its not hard to hydrate a value object (simplified, no error handling):

```
public object GetValueObject(string ClassTypePlusID)
{
    var type = ClassTypePlusID.Substring(0, 1);
    int.TryParse(ClassTypePlusID.Substring(1, 1), out var id);

    if (type == "A")
    {
        return new ValueObjectA() { ID = id };
    }
    else if (type == "B")
    {
        return new ValueObjectB() { ID = id };
    }
    else if (type == "C")
    {
        return new ValueObjectC() { ID = id };
    }
}
```

Then, I have three GetData() methods to get the data related to the object (again, vastly simplified here):

```
    private void GetData(ValueObjectA A)
    {
        // SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE ID=A.ID
    }
    private void GetData(ValueObjectB B)
    {
        // SELECT * FROM TableB WHERE ID=B.ID
    }
    private void GetData(ValueObjectC C)
    {
        // SELECT * FROM TableC WHERE ID=C.ID
    }
```

So finally, we get to my source of pain...  Now I need to feed that value object to a method.  But I have to (re)cast the object to its correct type before it is useful as a parameter.  I can't do something like this:

```
var valueObject = GetValueObject(urlParameter);
GetData(valueObject);
```

The compiler (rightly so I suppose) can't convert from object to ObjectA, ObjectB, or ObjectC.  So I have to do this ridiculous contortion for it:

```
    var valueObject = GetValueObject("A1");
    if (valueObject is ObjectA)
    {
        GetData((ValueObjectA)valueObject);
    }
    else if (valueObject is ObjectB)
    {
        GetData((ValueObjectB)valueObject);
    }
    else if (valueObject is ObjectC)
    {
        GetData((ValueObjectC)valueObject);
    }
```

To add insult to injury, I'm not done with the if statements yet, because I have to use them again in the View to be able to display the data object (whichever one it may be).

So I've been chasing my tail trying to figure out how I can do this without all the ugly (and hard to maintain) if statements.  There has to be an OOP way to do this, but I'm struggling to figure out what it is.

**EDIT:  OK, so as I figured, the first recommendations are to use inheritance.  So let me try that and maybe you can tell me what I'm missing.**

I do understand the basics of inheritance and polymorphism, but I am still learning how to use them effectively (as you can see)...

So if I'm to use inheritance, I need to have an abstract class that has common properties/behavior between the objects that are going to do the inheriting.  I don't see anything in common.  The `GetData` methods I was showing in my example would utilize a Repository specific to the object, and return (or store) a DTO in the ViewModel so the View can gain access to it.  So the input to the method isn't common (it would be one of the three value objects), and the output from the method isn't common (it would be one of three distinct DTOs that contain the data from the corresponding table).

I'm not arguing that inheritance or polymorphism isn't the answer (I'm sure it is), I'm just not figuring out how to leverage it.

**EDIT #2:**  In my attempt to simplify the question I may have gone too far.  Apologies for the moving target and not phrasing my question properly the first time, it was not my intent.

In the original question, I attempted to infer that ObjectA, B, and C were actual value objects (per DDD), but I never came out and said it explicitly.  So I'm saying it now, and I updated the example code to hopefully reinforce that better.

There are a few problems with moving the `GetData` method into the Value Object.  First off, I don't think it belongs there.  The ValueObject's purpose is to describe a particular type of ID.  It is used in several entities in my domain.  Another problem is that the `GetData` method was simplified (maybe too much) in my example here, and it actually has additional ID parameters that go in to it (that are also pulled from the URL).  From there, the `GetData` method will utilize various repositories to fill the view model with the data it needs (from multiple data sets).  So the bottom line here is that I'm at the application services layer here.  And I don't believe that the `GetData` method belongs inside of a value object in the domain layer.

Hopefully this clarifies the question/problem better (but I feel like I could certainly do better, and I'll keep thinking about it and update if I come up with anything).

Comment: Are you familiar with inheritance? Can your A, B, and C objects inherit from a single abstract base class? That cascading `if` is a classic problem that inheritance solves rather nicely.

Comment: Added in some more verbiage to the original question...  If there is common properties/behavior, I'm not seeing it (or looking for it in the wrong place).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would the following work?

I am unclear about whether the GetData() method is supposed to be something done by your objects or done on your class that has instantiated them. If you want to avoid if else blocks, you are going to need to either know upfront what properties they have in common so you can declare an appropriate interface, or you are going to delegate the responsibility to get the data to the object itself (as I have done below by implementing an IDataProvider interface).

I have used a dictionary to map between your various strings and the Type itself (only done A and B, but you can extend this). I have used Generics to solve your typecasting discomfort, but you may not even need to know the type because to your caller class, the importance is that it can GetData(), not what the class is. I have shown this in the test case with c, which could have equally held an instance of ObjectB.

```
public interface IDataProvider
{
    void GetData();
}
public class ObjectA : IDataProvider
{
    public ObjectA(int id)
    {
        this.Id = id;
    }

    public int Id
    {
        get;
    }

    public void GetData()
    {
        // Get A's data
    }
}
public class ObjectB : IDataProvider
{
    public ObjectB(int id)
    {
        this.Id = id;
    }

    public int Id
    {
        get;
    }

    public void GetData()
    {
        // Get B's data
    }
}

public static class ObjectFactory
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, Type> typeByNameDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Type>();

    static ObjectFactory()
    {
        typeByNameDictionary.Add("A", typeof(ObjectA));
        typeByNameDictionary.Add("B", typeof(ObjectB));            
    }

    public static bool TryGetObject<T>(string classTypePlusId, out T createdObject) where T : class 
    {
        string objectName = classTypePlusId.Substring(0, 1);
        if (!int.TryParse(classTypePlusId.Substring(1, 1), out int id))
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(classTypePlusId, "something meaningful");
        }

        if (!typeByNameDictionary.TryGetValue(objectName, out Type objectType))
        {
            createdObject = default(T);
            return false;
        }
        createdObject = Activator.CreateInstance(objectType, id) as T;
        return createdObject != null;
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class Test
{
    [Test]
    public void CanCreateObjects()
    {
        ObjectA a;
        ObjectB b;
        IDataProvider c;

        Assert.That(ObjectFactory.TryGetObject("A1", out a), Is.True);
        Assert.That(a.Id, Is.EqualTo(1));
        a.GetData();

        Assert.That(ObjectFactory.TryGetObject("A1", out b), Is.False);
        Assert.That(ObjectFactory.TryGetObject("B4", out b), Is.True);
        Assert.That(b.Id, Is.EqualTo(4));
        b.GetData();            
        Assert.That(ObjectFactory.TryGetObject("A2", out c), Is.True);
        c.GetData();
    }
}
```

**Edit 1: Based on comment below:**

You have two ways forward if you do not want your service layer code to be aware of how to load those objects. Drop the IDataProvider interface I suggested

*1. Hide the implementation of your objects behind an interface*

If the objects are all from the point of view of your service layer identical, you can declare an interface like (for example):

```
public interface IObjectWithCommonProperties
{
    int Id
    {
        get;
    }

    string StoredProcName
    {
        get;
    }

    bool IsSomeOtherFact
    {
        get;
    }

            // etc
}
```

You can then declare your ObjectA, ObjectB and ObjectC to support these. In this way, your service's GetData method simply accepts a IObjectWithCommonProperties parameter. (Please pick a better name than me) and treats them the same.

*2. Delegate your objects GetData to another class*

This would be the approach if the Objects don't have sufficient in common to handle using interfaces in (1). Having the main service layer class do everything is no doubt an egregious violation single responsibility principle, but you can still delegate the object loading to another class which doesn't have to be your dto itself.

```
public interface IObjectBuilder
{
    object GetCreateObjectWithData(string classPlusId);
}

public class ObjectABuilder : IObjectBuilder
{
    public object GetCreateObjectWithData(string classPlusId)
    {
        ObjectA loadedObject;
        ObjectFactory.TryGetObject(classPlusId, out loadedObject);

        loadedObject.SomeProperty = "someValue"; // etc
        return loadedObject;
    }
}
```

Construct an appropriate IObjectBuilder for each type of object (they can share a common ancestor class if 95% is the same). Then register this in your object factory so that for a given classPlusId, you get returned the appropriate IObjectBuilder implementation (rather than the object itself); Your service layer can just GetCreateObjectWithData on the interface variable without caring for what that will do. This greatly simplifies the testing of your service layer too, because you can substitute these IObjectBuilder instances with mocks.

Comment: I like your use of the Factory Pattern.  And in the end, I will likely use something like that instead of what I've shown here in my simplified example.  See updated question...  ObjectA, B, and C are in fact value objects in the domain, and I don't believe that the GetData behavior belongs there.  I think it belongs in the application services layer (where I'm at in my question).

Comment: I have added an Edit to my answer. See if that leads anywhere.

Comment: The key that got my brain on the right path was the "they can share a common ancestor class".  I had my Value Objects (A, B, and C) descend from a common parent class and was then able to eliminate a bunch of if statements and get the code that did the work were it needed to be.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Jay's answer, here's how you would implement an [interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface):

```
public interface IObject
{
    int ID { get; set; }
}
```

The interface ideally defines all of the methods and properties in common between your otherwise unrelated classes.  You've already implemented this interface, so you would just add the interface like this:

```
public class ObjectA() : IObject
```

In order to really make this interface useful, I'd recommend moving your `GetData` methods within their related classes.  That way, you could modify your interface to include that method:

```
public interface IObject
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    void GetData();
}
```

Having done that, you can change the signature of your `GetGetValueObject` method to return your interface:

```
public IObject GetValueObject(string ClassTypePlusID)
```

Then, instead of checking the type of your object, you can simply call its GetData method:

```
var valueObject = GetValueObject("A1"); //var is of type IObject
ObjectA.GetData();
```

Comment: See updated question...  This is the path I was trying to go down, but it didn't fit the way I have things structured to this point.  My `ObjectA` is an actual value object meant only to represent a particular type of ID in my domain.  I don't believe that it is supposed to have behavior.  And even if it did, I don't think that the GetData behavior belongs in the domain, it belongs in application services layer.

Comment: I see how an extension method would allow me to place the behavior in a more logical location, but I don't see how that absolves me of using the messy if statements and explicit type conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you have an Interface which you can just adhere to and then have a single function and remove all the branching... also the int.parse is superficial along with the substring and are terrible practices to allocate such small short lived heap objects... you only need the char which is string[0] and string[1] for the Id...

Comment: While I agree with using an interface, the rest of your answer might not necessarily apply.  This is a simplified example, after all.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are poo-pooing my use of `Substring` and `TryParse`.  This example was simplified.  The type identifier and id could both be longer than one character and one digit.  I would love to have an interface with a single function that would remove all the branching.  Care to enlighten me as to how I do that (maybe with an example abstract class applicable to my example)?

Comment: Aren't you the consultant?

Comment: @Jay - Me?  I'm a recovering procedural programmer, trying to learn and apply OOP.  And I'm also flying solo here on my own project (I don't work with any other programmers).  If you are implying that I'm supposed to "know how to do this", then why does this wonderful site even exist?

Comment: I don't think this is functional vs OO, same would apply there... this site exists to answer  questions not write your code, if your question  was how to compose the interface it's answered otherwise try code review stack exchange

Comment: I could argue that I believe this question is OK for SO, but I'm open to taking it elsewhere.  And seeing how there hasn't been a quick and simple answer (what I thought it would be) here, I can see how it might fit better over at Code Review.  Please flag my question for closure if you feel it doesn't belong.